# Apply where condition if it exists in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

is there a way in rails activerecord to apply the where condition based on a condition ?

For example:
Say I want to apply the filter if it is present in the input parameters.
Assume @name is a mandatory field and @salary is an optional field.

```
@name = "test_name"
@salary = 2000
```

I want to do something like below:

```
Employee.where(name: @name)
        .where(salary: @salary) if @salary.present?
```

I know to make it in multiple db calls, but I'm looking for an option to make this happen in a single db call.

Comment: how about ransack gem? It a search mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query only by parameters that are present:

```
args = { name: @name, salary: @salary.presence }
Employee.where(args.compact)
```

Comment: Alternatively `args = { name: @name, salary: @salary.presence }.compact`

Answer (score 6):

You can assign the result of the 1st `where` to a variable and invoke the 2nd `where` conditionally:

```
@employees = Employee.where(name: @name)
@employees = @employees.where(salary: @salary) if @salary.present?
```

Comment: will this not make multiple db calls ?

Comment: @vishwastej I used to have same concern as you :). You should watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough

Comment: It _looks_ like it will in the console, because the console tries to give you immediate feedback, and thus runs things immediately; but Rails doesn't execute the query until it needs the results of the query for something. In the console you can run `@employees = Employee.where(name: @name); nil` and see it doesn't actually run a query there

Comment: i tried this. but in the console I could see the output of @employees = Employee.where(name: @name) and not nil.

Comment: `a = obj.foo.bar` and `a = obj.foo; a = a.bar` gives the same result. Methods aren't aware of any chaining and therefore can't behave differently.

Comment: Alternatively you can wrap the code in a `begin`/`end` statement to execute everything at once.

Comment: @3limin4t0r a `begin` / `end` block is for [exception handling](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html). What do you mean by _"execute everything at once"_?

Comment: @Stefan When I run code in an irb console, and don't want the console to execute queries in-between lines (due to the fact that results are displayed using `inspect`) or when code is `.` prefixed to chain further on the previous line. You can simply open a block (with `begin`), copy the code in and `end` the block. So what I mean with "execute everything at once" is basically, don't execute on a per line basis.

Comment: @3limin4t0r got it. I thought you meant `begin`/`end` in general. In a REPL it’s actually quite neat.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add all possible arguments into one hash and remove the ones that are `nil` with [`Hash#compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-compact):

```
Employee.where({ name: @name, salary: @salary }.compact)
```

Comment: Note that this fails as soon as `@salary` is an empty string. `compact` only removes `nil` values and not empty strings. OP uses `present?` in the question, which also checks for empty strings. Otherwise a good solution.